# OpenAI api - asynchronous API calls

Tags: python, python-asyncio, openai-api

I work with the OpenAI API. I have extracted slides text from a PowerPoint presentation, and written a prompt for each slide. Now, I want to make asynchronous API calls,
so that all the slides are processed at the same time.

this is the code from the async main function:

```
for prompt in prompted_slides_text:
    task = asyncio.create_task(api_manager.generate_answer(prompt))
    tasks.append(task)
results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

and this is generate_answer function:

```
@staticmethod
    async def generate_answer(prompt):
        """
        Send a prompt to OpenAI API and get the answer.
        :param prompt: the prompt to send.
        :return: the answer.
        """
        completion = await openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]

        )
        return completion.choices[0].message.content
```

the problem is:

> object OpenAIObject can't be used in 'await' expression

and I don't know how to await for the response in generate_answer function

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using asyncio for Non-async Functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050315/using-asyncio-for-non-async-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those landing here, the error here was probably the instantiation of the object. It has to be:

```
client = AsyncOpenAI(api_key=api_key)
```

Then you can use:

```
        response = await client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=custom_prompt,
        temperature=0.9
    )
```

Answer (score 15):

**Note**: With version v1 the api has changed and this answer is not valid anymore, see [Graciela's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77539674/3007402) answer for the new API.

---

You have to use `openai.ChatCompletion.acreate` to use the api asynchronously.

It's documented on their Github - https://github.com/openai/openai-python#async-usage

Comment: The api has a limit of 3 requests per minute, and my program is crashed because of it, do you know how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: @DanielG I had written another answer that limits concurrent requests - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67831742/3007402. See if that helps. You will find more answers at - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48483348/3007402

Comment: Still it does not work.

Comment: @Brana What specifically doesn't work? Can you share your code? You may want to ask a new question.

Comment: I think this used to be correct but now the answer by Graciela is correct.